# Android + Phonegap + XML data

Tags: jquery, android, xml, sqlite, cordova

I`m developing a Phonegap Android app that is some kind of catalogue and products search. It have a synchronization with the server intranet, that provides all data.

The problem is that the app is all developed, with exception of synchronization that is crashing. I noticed that the problem is with XML parsing.

The synchronization is a HTML with a button. With button clicked, it starts an JS function like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url : "file:///android_asset/xml/produtos.xml",
     data : "{}",
     async : false,
     cache : false,
     dataType : "xml",
}).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
     alert(xhr.status);
     alert(thrownError);
}).done(function(data) {
     // search all data, download all files from XML URL tag (used this: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Downloader), construct SQLite statements and throw it in an Array for late DB transaction
     if($(data).find("produtos").length > 0 && $(data).find("produtos").eq(0).find("produto").length > 0) {
          $(data).find("produtos").eq(0).find("produto").each(function() {
               i++;
               produtos[i] = "CONSTRUCT SQL STATEMENT WITH XML PARSED DATA LIKE $(this).find('nome').text()";
          }
     }
});
```

The XML file is very large, about 700kb, with about 1800 products. Each product have about 10 direct nodes inside and about 5 childs with other 10 nodes inside (details, images, related products, etc.). So, each product have about 80 nodes. 1800 * 80 = 144000 nodes in my XML. Also, each product have about 5 URL nodes that are files to download (I'm using https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Downloader plugin).

If I start the synchronization with downloads, it stops by memory leak (something about 512mb, don't remember the right message, but I can post it tomorrow). If I start the sync without downloads (just XML parse) it takes about 30 minutes and don't do anything (feels like proccessing, but do nothing). I don't know if there is other options to sync this initial data (other syncs are made by passing last sync timestamp by parameter). Do you guys have some problem or (likely) solution? If you need more information, ask me, I need your help with this.

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to split your xml file in more digestible chunks. 144,000 nodes is not reasonable for a mobile/JS app :-) Of course the question is, do you control the production of the xml catalog?

Comment: Other company manage the server app and production of XML catalog, they are very close to my company but I don't think they'll change this... I'll try.

In case of reject, do you know what is the best "reasonable" quantity of nodes in a XML to parse by some mobile/JS application?

I searched this past weekend about Java XML parsing and I'm wondering how much better it will be than jQuery XML parsing. Do you know if change my sync to a Android Java Service will solve this?

Comment: Hard to know 100% for sure -- and my Android phone might have less or more memory than yours :-) I suggest you do tests: 1,000 nodes, 2K, 5K, 10K etc. See where it starts to go south of reasonable in terms of processing time. Also, you might want to leave the heavy lifting to the big guns: download the file with the FileDownloader plugin, and write a plugin to do the parsing in Java -- maybe with Sax, to send back regular feedback to the app.

Comment: Another solution is to use a proxy xml transport on your own server, i.e. inplace of your phonegap application pulling the xml directly, your proxy script on your server pulls xml from the 3rd party and caches it on your server. Then it breaks it down in manageable chunks for consumption of your phonegap application (phonegap app will send requests to your proxy script and not the 3rd party server).

Comment: The server app guys changed its code to chunk node blocks into another xml. So, I can parse the xml files in 4 or 5 separated times. Now, I have other problem. The first sync (load ALL data) is loaded in about 10 min. So, I want to play some progress bar. I used the jQuery UI Progressbar, but I can't update the UI since my $.ajax calls are async:false (because I need to execute SQL statements, I'm running all sync JS into a transaction block)... any help with this? Thank you, guys! You are awesome! =)